# Tratar erro do Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Possuo um script de inserção e gostaria de poder exibir ao usuário uma mensagem personalizada para a seguinte mensagem de tentativa de cadastro de um registro já existente:

```
Duplicate entry '42-1' for key 'PRIMARY'.
```

Tentei usar alguns exemplos como:

```
mysql_errno($link) e mysql_error($link)
```

Mas não consegui exibir o resultado, a mensagem não aparece, tenho a seguinte linha em meu código que mostra a mensagem não tratada:

```
$aretorno["msg"] = "Ocorreu um erro na inclus&atilde;o dos dados: " . $stmt->error . ". Verifique.";
$aretorno["status"] = "ERRO";
```

A mensagem exibida é essa:

```
Ocorreu um erro na inclusão dos dados: Duplicate entry '42-1' for key 'PRIMARY'. Verifique.
```

O código da tentativa de gravação com chave primária duplicada e tentativa de exibir a mensagem tratada é esse:

```
if ($_POST["Operacao"] == 'FaseObrigatoria') {

    $sql = "INSERT INTO gerFaseObrigatoria (IdContrato, IdTipoFase, Ordem) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

    if($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql) ){
        $bind = $stmt->bind_param(
            "iii",          
            $_POST["IdContrato"],
            $_POST["IdTipoFase1"],
            $_POST["iOrdem"]
        );
            // EXECUTANDO A QUERY
            if($stmt->execute()){
                $aretorno["msg"] = "Registro inserido com sucesso.";
                $aretorno["par"] = $_POST["IdContrato"];
            } else {
                $aretorno["msg"] = "Ocorreu um erro na inclusão dos dados: " . $stmt->mysql_error($conn) . ". Verifique.";
                $aretorno["status"] = "ERRO";
            }
    } else {
        $aretorno["msg"] = "Ocorreu um erro na preparação dos dados: "  . $stmt->error . ". Verifique.";
        $aretorno["status"] = "ERRO";
    }
}
```

Tentei pegar o erro assim:

```
mysql_errno($conn) == 1451)
```

Comment: Coloca o código da consulta e como está pegando/tratando o erro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ao ocorrer uma falha do insert pode enviar ao usuário uma mensagem genérica, quando a falha for por um item duplicado(1062), pegue o sqlstate(código do erro) especifico e comparar dentro de um if. [mysqli_errno ou $errno](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.errno.php) do MySQLi retornam o código do erro o primeiro é para o estilo procedural o segundo para o orientado a objetos.

```
if(!$stmt->execute()){
   if($stmt->errno == 1062){
       echo 'erro ao cadastras, essa informação já existe no banco';
   }
}
```

[Lista com códigos de erros do MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-messages-server.html)

Comment: Obrigado @rray, a sua ajuda foi excelente, problema resolvido.

Comment: Essa referência também me ajudou. TKS

Comment: Lista com códigos de erros do MySQL -> Page Not Found. Sabe onde tem do MySQL_i