# Como capturar o erro 1452 do MySQL e apresentar mensagem ao usuário?

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho a função abaixo que faz a inserção de um novo registro em um Banco de Dados.

```js
// INSERE UM NOVO REGISTRO NO BANCO DE DADOS
function save($table = null, $data = null) {
 $_SESSION['message'] = null;
 $_SESSION['type'] = null;
 $database = open_database();
 $columns = null;
 $values = null;
 foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
  $columns .= trim($key, "'") . ", ";
  $values .= "'$value', ";
 }
 $columns = rtrim($columns, ', ');
 $values = rtrim($values, ', ');
 $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $table . " ($columns) " . "VALUES " . "($values);";
 //echo $sql; //usado apenas para depurar
 try {
  $database->query($sql);
  if (!$database->errno == 1452) {
   echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Existe uma Informação duplicada no Banco de Dados');</script>";
  }
  $_SESSION['message'] = "Registro inserido com sucesso!";
  $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';
 } catch (Exception $e) {
  $_SESSION['message'] = 'Nao foi possivel realizar a operacao!';
  $_SESSION['type'] = 'danger';
 }
 close_database($database);
}
```

Não estou conseguindo pegar o código de erro do MySQL e apresentar uma mensagem ao usuário. Nesse caso aqui, problemas com referência.

Usei esse link aqui do fórum como orientação, mas não deu certo: [Tratar erro do Mysql](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/114627/tratar-erro-do-mysql)

Onde estou errando?

Comment: mas qual seria o erro retornado com essas configurações, qual erro você está recebendo ?

Comment: @MichaelCosta quando faço um cadastro normalmente pelo formulário, os dados não são gravados. Então eu descomento a linha onde faço um echo $sql e com isso o sistema me mostra a instrução sql completa. Se eu copiar essa instrução e executar no banco de dados diretamente, o MySQL informa falta de integridade com erro 1452.

Comment: posta aqui a instrução completa que é enviada no $sql..

Comment: Até onde eu entendi você quer mostrar uma msg pro usuário sobre o erro... mas você sabe que esse erro, é porque está tentando cadastrar algo no banco, que depende de uma chave que provavelmente não está cadastrada ? uma foreign key.. você realmente só quer tratar o erro mesmo ?

Comment: tipo para dizer ao usuário, que primeiro ele deve cadastrar 'ABC' para depois cadastrar 'XYZ'

Comment: isso mesmo @MichaelCosta vc pode ver que tentei pegar o erro no código mas não deu certo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mano.. entendi seu problema.. você fez uma inversão do seu **true false**, para **false true**. quando adicionou if(! exclamação) dentro do seu if.
por isso não está funcionando.

**troque isso**

```
if (!$database->errno == 1452) {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Existe uma Informação duplicada no Banco de Dados');</script>";
        }
```

**por isso**

```
if ($database->errno == 1452) {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Existe uma Informação duplicada no Banco de Dados');</script>";
        }
```

acredito que seja só esse o problema.
vlw.

Lembrando que esse erro, não é de duplicidade, como você se refere no Alert do seu javascript. e sim que "X" só pode ser cadastrado depois que "Y" for cadastrado.